# Interface Builder strange interface error

Tags: ios, interface-builder, swift

I am having a strange error on my builds. When i design my view in interface builder, everything looks fine. As soon as I run my app on my iPhone, everything messes up. The buttons I use are smushed into the top left corner of the screen, and the font size does not change, even though I have proper settings for all screen sizes. The labels A and B work fine though. This is very puzzling to me. This is not the only view which I am having this error with. Here are pictures to detail my problem further:

[image: View seen in interface builder]

This is the view I see in interface builder.

The view I see when I run my app on my phone is quite different.

[image: View seen on my phone]

Why am I seeing the views so differently? Why are the buttons being smushed to the top right of the screen when I run my app?

Comment: How are the constraints set up, and are the views in correct hierarchy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't have sufficient constraints on those buttons for the runtime to know how to place them. Usually constraint issues will show up at build/design time with a yellow or red circle in the tree view for the storyboard/xib. Try using "[reset to suggested constraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/articles-autolayout/resolve_view_layout_issues_quickly.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009971-CH37-SW1)"